# What is the time complexity of the best case to insert a new node into a minimum-level BST with n nodes?

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

I am learning about algo complexity and calculating time complexity. the question is

What is the time complexity of the best case to insert a new node into a 
minimum-level BST with n nodes? Explain. (Hint: You may draw a diagram as part of your 
solution.)

Can you please explain in details how you would solve this question and similar questions?

my attempt:

for time complexity we have 2 questions, how many times and what does it cost.

How many times: 
there will be one element to check so => O(1)
how much does it cost?
how many times?

now I am stuck here (pretty early), I am assuming that since its a tree, there will be n/2 elements after the first comparison and it keeps splitting into half.

Comment: How far have you gotten on this, and where are you stuck?

Comment: What is a minimum-level BST? Does it mean that the tree is balanced?

Comment: sorry BST == binary search tree

Comment: @ScottHunter I will put what I have in the question...

Comment: @ScottHunter I added what I have so far

Comment: @AhouraGhotbi *hint* how many times can you divide `n` by `2`?

Comment: @C.B. to be honest I am not sure...

Comment: ["A minimum-level binary tree has all levels full except the last level"](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:foxBifz1Z90J:www.math.yorku.ca/~zyang/2620m/Lecture%25204aPost.ppt+&cd=6&hl=en&ct=clnk) - well, that took a while to find. Really not a well-known concept.

Comment: @Dukeling thats my prof's paper :)

Comment: @C.B. is it logn? is the final answer O(logn)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following minimum-height BST (any binary tree with `8` nodes has at least 4 levels, thus it has the minimum height).

```
         8
        / 
       4
     /   \
    2     6
   / \   / \
  1   3 5   7
```

Now let's say you insert the value `9`, it will go straight to the right side of the root.

To generalize this example: a BST which has a right child or left child which are **complete** trees- is a minimum height BST. If the other side is empty, any value that you'll insert which will be greater\lesser to the node will be added directly to the root's right\left child. in this case the insert will take `O(1)` time.

Comment: ok so thanks everything is clear except with the insertion process you explained. so if one side of the BST is empty (like your example) it wont matter if the element is larger or smaller than the root element, it will be automatically added to the empty side of the tree? or is that because 9 is larger than 8

Comment: @AhouraGhotbi It does matter, if the left side of the root is a complete tree (all the values are smaller than the root) and the right side is empty, then inserting a value greater the root will take `O(1)` (goes directly to the roots right child). It goes the other way if the root's right side is a complete tree, then a smaller value then the root will be inserted in `O(1)`

Comment: ok gotcha, one last thing, let say we have a tree like : http://imgur.com/xEPJfo8  and you want to insert 12 in it, 12 goes on the left of 15 correct?

Comment: It's a [minimum-level binary tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22078331/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-the-best-case-to-insert-a-new-node-into-a-minimum?noredirect=1#comment33484141_22078331), not a minimum-height one.